# Do timed buffs drain in paused games?

Tags: diablo-iii

Do buffs like Nephalem Valor, timed skills, and that of shrines deplete in paused solo games?

Comment: This is easily testable.  This shouldn't even be a question.

Comment: The FAQ suggests asking *practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face*. Wondering whether your buffs are running out while you paused the game to answer a call (for example) seems like an actual problem to me, and I don't see anything else in the FAQs to suggest that you have to test things yourself before asking. This seems like a fine question to me, +1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No.**  The entire game is paused: including any buffs' and debuffs' timers.

Answer (score 5):

If you by paused mean you hit escape then no. Just tested it.

Comment: I can confirm this; I also tested it.